# Handling new PHP session request from same visitor

Tags: php, apache, session, cakephp, cookies

I use  **PHP 5.4.36, Apache/2.2.15, CakePHP 2.5.6.**

When a visitor clicks "login" button, I check for **session** data.

- If user is already logged in, I redirect user to members section.
- If user isn't logged in, but user has login remember cookie I also redirect user to members section.
- If user isn't logged in, no rememberme cookie, I redirect user to signin form.
- If user isn't logged in, rememberme cookies exists, but no session id cookie and no session file, I create new session and session cookie.

**So for the last case, sometimes users can open 2 simultaneous login pages.

In that case 2 tabs are opened.**

- **First tab**: Connects with server, no session exists, no session id cookie exists, rememberme cookie exists. New session file created, session id cookie created and user logged in.
- **Second tab**: Connects with server, finds no session, finds no session id cookie, finds rememberme cookie. Because first tab still tries to signin and session file and session id cookie isn't created, new session is created.

Request time between these two tabs are nearly 0.5-1.5 seconds. If difference becomes more than 2 seconds no problem exists.

This issue becomes 1 times in 1000 requests, but is it possible to disable this problem ?

Edit:
I don't want user to login with different usernames at the same time. I want user to login just 1 time. But in this case 2 sessions created with same credentials. So system uses last session. And previous session becomes reduntant. Also my database records shows two different logins, although user logged in just once.

Comment: you want give user possibility to login with two different username at the same time? in two different tab in the same browser?

Comment: Any updates on the question so far?

Comment: @Naruto nope, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

We limit multiple logins based on the same session, but it's far from perfect.

We have a model in addition to Session which tracks: user_id, session_id, user_agent, IP.  If the user has more than 1 record matching 3 of the 4 matching, we assume it's the double-window bug and kill the session.

This isn't flawless, but it's been ok for us, you might want to implement something along these lines if it's something that's still bothering you.